# How to adjust the margin of Safari Reading List?

Tags: iphone, safari, reading-list

iPhone Safari is wasting a lot of screen space in Reading List mode:

[image]

Is it possible to adjust the width of left and right margin?

Comment: I think that you are confusing the Reading List and the, newer, Reader mode. These are two different features of Safari.